# AppleScript do shell script returns error for "which" command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that will ask a user which remote cloud service and then which bucket they would like to mount in Mac OS using [rclone](https://rclone.org/). But in order to run the `rclone` command in an AppleScript, you need to include the entire path to the app. For me that is: `/usr/local/bin/rclone`

I want to include, as a variable, the location of rclone using the `which` command in a shell script like this:

```
set rcloneLOC to paragraphs of (do shell script "which rclone")
```

But I get a script error stating "The command exited with a non-zero status." This happens even if I just try to run `do shell script "which rclone"` by itself. If I type `which rclone` into terminal, I get the result I expect.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: `which` won't help here, because it searches for the command in the same places that the shell would if you just used the command name directly. Specifically, both `which` and the shell search the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. `do shell script` runs its commands with a pretty basic environment, so neither will be able to find it without a full path.

Comment: I’m a little confused. When I type `which rclone` into terminal, no matter my path, it works. But not in the AppleScript, which you’ve explained is due to its environment (which I don’t fully understand, I’m a hobbyist at this, not a pro). So how would I find the path to rclone using AppleScript? I am hoping to give this script to a few friends and colleagues, but we all run different versions of macOS. So I want to make sure the path to rclone is found and correct. The rest of this should work fine.

Comment: `PATH` is different from your working path. You can check its value in your interactive shell with `echo "$PATH"`. It's a colon-delimited list of directories to search for executables, and you'll see that it includes `/usr/local/bin` as one of the entries. Now open Script Editor and try running the AppleScript `do shell script "echo \"$PATH\""` and you'll see that it *doesn't* include that directory. The difference is because your interactive shells run several setup scripts that (among other things) add more entries to the shell's `PATH`. I don't know the best way to do this from AppleScript.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson suggests, you can see your path using 'echo $PATH'. To change the applescript's path (and view the change) try `do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; echo $PATH"` which will prepend usrlocalbin to the path, and then echo the updated path. Note that this edit will vanish once the shell script is finished. So you need to combine the commands, like so: `do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; which rsync"`. I use rsync because I don't have rclone installed. The result is `"/usr/local/bin/rsync"`

Comment: It seems the shell used by `do shell script` doesn't have the directory of `rclone` on its `PATH`, possibly because it's a very basic shell. You could try to run a more modern shell that may have `rclone` on its `PATH`. I would try `do shell script "zsh -c 'which date'"`

Comment: @Mockman This did it! Thank you! I really appreciate the input from you and GordonDavisson on this. The whole "environments" thing is a bit of a mystery to me, but I'm still probably a beginner, maybe intermediate, at all this. You should re-submit your comment as an answer, and I will mark it as such. Thank you again! (also, if you happen to know of a guide or something that explains environments, I would really love to learn more outside of whatever Google searching randomness gives me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GordonDavisson suggests, you can view your path using `echo $PATH`.

To change your applescript's path (and view the change) try this:

```
do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; echo $PATH"
```

The first part of the shell command (up to the semi-colon) will prepend `/usr/local/bin` to your default path. The second part will return your updated path. The semi-colon has the second part run after the first part is finished.

It's important to note that this change is temporary and only in effect for this shell script and only while it is operating. This is why you need the combined commands in order to see the effect.

I'll use 'rsync' as an example since I don't have rclone; substitute 'rclone' to get its path. To get its path, you combine the `export` command with `which`, like so:

```
do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; which rsync"
```

The result is `/usr/local/bin/rsync`.

To clarify a couple of things… the environment is a set of conditions that apply for each user. You can get a basic rundown of it by running `man 7 environ` in Terminal. There is an `env` command which lists your settings and allows you to edit them; `man env` will provide info on it. At the bottom of these man pages, you should see references to related commands which you can also look up. Meanwhile, from within Script Editor, you could run a 1-line script with `do shell script "env"` and see the corresponding environment for applescript's shell.

Based on Apple's documentation (or my interpretation of it), they chose this setup because it is relatively secure and portable. You know what you get every time you run a shell script. You don't need to use a more *modern* shell to run the `which` command. You can modify the environment as needed, the same way you would while using the terminal.

Finally, Apple has provided [Technical Note 2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) which provides info on using shell scripts with applescript. Also, you can likely get more info here or on the [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/env) stack exchange.

NB All of the above is just my understanding, which is limited.